# Spectral coordinates on Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-groups, diagonalization, hermitian-matrices

Both in [Venezianni and Pereira, A note on the volume form of normal matrix space](http://professor.ufabc.edu.br/%7Etiago.pereira/Coordinate.pdf), it is claimed that the decomposition of a normal matrix $M=U\Lambda U^\dagger$ with $\Lambda=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_N)$ and $U\in U(N)$ is unique up to multiplication by phases of the rows of $U$. However, there is also an ambiguity in the ordering of the eigenvalues and the rows of $U$, right? Why can we forget this ambiguity to create a chart on the space of normal matrices based on $\Lambda$ and $U$ that covers an open set of full measure?

Comment: The authors probably assume that $M$ has distinct eigenvalues, otherwise the claim is not true. Consider the identity matrix as a counterexample. Also, it is each column, not each row, that is uniquely determined up to a scalar $e^{i\theta}$ on the unit circle. This is true because the eigenspaces are one-dimensional when the eigenvalues are distinct.

Comment: But, even assuming that the eigenvalues are distinct, we can always reorder them in $\Lambda$ and in $U$ (the ordering of the eigenbasis is not determined by $M$). How do we know that we can choose an ordering consistently throughout all of the space of normal matrices?

Comment: It seems the paper is only interested in *local* coordinates, so it's not necessary to choose a globally consistent orientation. All that's needed is that, given a decomposition $M=U\Lambda U^\dagger$, we can find neighborhoods around $M$ and $(\Lambda,U)$ such that the decomposition is a smooth bijection between those neighborhoods. This cannot be done everywhere, but it can be done *almost everywhere* in some ensembles.